# Storing/creating local table from linked SQL table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a linked table in my access database (dbo_Billing_denied (DSN=WTSTSQL05_BB;DATABASE=DEPTFINANCE), etc.) and I want to create a table that will store the data from this linked into local table, so I can use it to run other queries. Currently I can use this because it tells me that it can not make connection (ODB--connection to 'WTSTSQL05_BB' failed.

Do I have to create a table first and assign all the fields before I can do this (create a table and fields that are same as what's in the linked table and than create append query to do this...)?

Comment: Have you tried a copy of the db and right-click on the table?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have two problems.  I will address the second one.  You will need to reestablish connection to the linked table before this will work.

You can use a "make table query" in Access to make a local copy of the linked table.  You can use the GUI for this, or you can structure the SQL something like this:

```
SELECT <list of various fields, or * for all fields>
INTO <name of new local table>
FROM <name of linked table(s) on the server>
WHERE <any other conditions you want to put on which records are included>;
```

I mentioned that there might be more than one table.  You can also do this with joined tables or unions etc.  The "where" clause is optional.  Removing it will copy the entire data set.

You will get a warning when you try to execute this query in Access.  It will tell you that you are about to write (or overwrite) a table.  If you are trying to write a cleaner application with fewer nuisance messages for the end user, call this query from a macro.  The macro would need to turn the warnings off, execute the query, then turn the warnings back on.

Microsoft Access does not require you to create this table before you write it; if the table does not exist Access will create this table for you, based on the field definitions in the source data.  If a table of the same name does exist, Access will drop this table from your database and then create a new table of that name.

This also implies that the local table you are generating will need a unique name.  If your query tries to overwrite the linked table by using the same name, the first thing Access will do is drop the linked table.  It will then look for field definitions and input data in the linked table that it just dropped.

Since the new local table will have a new name, queries developed for the linked table will not work with the new local table.  One possible work-around would be to rename the linked table in your local Access database.  The table name in Access does not need to equal the name in the database it's linking to.  The query could then write to a table with the correct name, and previous queries should work.  Still, keep in mind that these queries would no longer be working on live data.